# How can i manage a small database without a mysql server?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a little project:

I want to make a system to manage a small library ( with 3000 books or so )

My idea was to use python with pymysql, but that would require mysql server be installed on the PC which will run this system.

My idea is to have one file with all the information of the books, i can work with an excel file, but what is your recomendation ?

Thanks , sorry about my english.

Comment: Check out sqlite and the `sqlite3` module for Python. Manages a database as a file entirely from your app.

Comment: [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) seems reasonable for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using SQLite and the the dataset package: https://github.com/pudo/dataset

easy and fast until you need something more complex